# if cell in range (partially) matches any value in list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get "Okay" if **any** cell in my sheet *Information $46:$46* matches text that is listed on another sheet in *Lists D6:D17*. My Formula works if the cells in *Information* only contain that value that is mentioned, the problem I now have is that the cells in *Information* sometimes contain multiple values

For example: I am looking for the words **red, blue** and **purple**,
If any cell in *Information* contains any of these in any way the result should be "Okay". Some cells will contain "red and green", the result should still be "Okay" because the cell contains **red**

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Information!$46:$46,'lists'!D6:D17)),"okay","")
```

I tried making the list an array or use * but so far I have not succeeded

Comment: You'd need wildcards but that would then match items like 'gathered' since it contains the word 'red'. Do you have any punctuation to worry about?

Comment: no that doesn't matter. but punctuation yes, there can be a comma or a dot or slash between the words. whatever people type to separate multiple "items".  e.g. red, blue, green  Or red/blue/green...  Or red. blue. green...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my example the formula is like this:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Information;"*"&D6:D8&"*"));"okay";"")
```

In your workbook the formula would be:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Information!$46:$46;"*"&Lists!$D$6:$D$8&"*"));"okay";"")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried something like that but I couldn't figure out how to place the * since the list is on another sheet ( called Lists). Do I put them before the sheet name or before the cell reference?

Comment: I apparently let a space:" " after some of the words I wanted to find, making them unfindable in a summation; red , blue, green while I obviously wanted to find red, blue, green. The * now also works as expected.

Comment: @user17269242 Ok, I updated the answer, to match the formula to your needs.